Asymptotic expression for the number of words that can be formed when a directed graph determines which letters can follow each other
If I have an alphabet of $n$ letters, and I ask how many words of $k$ letters can I form, the answer is $n^k$, because any letter can follow any other letter. But let's suppose that a graph dictates the rules on which letter can follow which other letter, such as the following:

Furthermore, suppose that you require that the word start from an initial node (in this case only one, B) and must end at a terminal node (here there are two, D and E). It seems that there are now far fewer than $n^k$ words satisfying these restrictions, and computer algorithms could enumerate all such words for a given $k$ to figure out how many words satisfy those restrictions.
I'm not interested so much in getting those exact numbers (I doubt that there's an analytic way to compute how many words there are that's better than just enumeration with a computer) as I am in understanding how the number of valid words grows with $k$, via some asymptotic expression.
If I am not mistaken, if $G$ is the adjacency matrix for this directed graph, then the number of strings of length $k$ beginning with B and ending in either E or D is $sG^{k-1}e$, where $s$ is an $n$-dimension vector with 1 in the position corresponding to the letter B and 0 everywhere else, and $e$ is similar except for both ending letters (E and D). I believe that the rate of growth depends on the number of cycles in the graph, but that's about all I can say about how quickly it grows. I cannot think of an approximation for the count that is more refined than a factorial growth, which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.
(In a previous version of this question, I wrote $s(G^{k-1}-G^{k-2})e$ instead; that's because I cared about strings that began in some start state, ended in a terminal state, and when in a terminal state the string could not expand; for example, BSEE is not allowed, but BSE is. I think answering the question for $sG^{k-1}e$ should suffice though.)

Why not just $s G^{k-1} e$?

@MishaLavrov Not entirely sure what you mean. If you mean why study $s(G^{k-1} - G^{k-2})e$ instead of $sG^{k-1}e$, I am interested in how many words of length $k$ exactly exist, but an asymptotic expression of $sG^{k-1}e$ would also work. But as for why not just keep that as the asymptotic expression, it tells me very little. The number of words could be 0, constant, growing, or growing rapidly. I want to relate the number of words to properties of $G$ like eigenvalues, number of cycles, etc., that provide more understanding of how the number of words grows.

$sG^{k-1}e$ counts words of length exactly $k$. I'm just not sure why you want to look at the difference in the number of words of length $k$ and length $k-1$.

@MishaLavrov Oh, I understand the point of confusion! In my conceptualization, when I enter a terminal state, the chain ends. So for example, there is no string BSEE, only BSE, a length-three string. (This problem is motivated by a situation where a process "dies" in a terminal state.) I'll restate the problem.

Are you perhaps putting a loop at vertices $D$ and $E$ (going from those vertices to themselves)? If so, that will force you to compute $G^{k-1} - G^{k-2}$; but you could also just not put a loop there, and then $G^{k-1}$ will be fine.

@MishaLavrov Now I'm more confused since putting a loop there seems to indicate the very thing I do not want ultimately: strings that expand as they remain in a termina state, since the loop seems to indicate the next element is the terminal string. While not putting a loop seems to indicate that the sequence has nowhere to go after D or E.

I agree. If you don't put a loop there, then $sG^{k-1}e$ is the correct formula. Anyway, all this is beside the point; I just wanted to understand the formula you were using to make sure that you're asking the question you wanted to ask (since some variants of the question like nonbacktracking walks in undirected graphs get even more complicated).

As a simple upper bound, the number of valid words is at most $\Delta^{k-1}$, where $\Delta$ is the maximum number of arrows out of any letter, because every additional letter multiplies the number of possibilities by $\Delta$.
This is also related to the more precise bound: the growth rate of entries of $G^k$ is bounded by $|\lambda(G)|^k$, where $\lambda(G)$ is the largest (in absolute value) eigenvalue of $G$. The Perron–Frobenius theorem gives us a few guarantees that the eigenvalue and eigenvector here won't misbehave too badly.
Actually, $\lambda(G)$ is only relevant if the corresponding eigenvector has positive entries on vertices (letters) that we can reach while solving the problem. One of the qualifiers in the Perron–Frobenius theorem says that the eigenvector is all-positive if the matrix $G$ is irreducible. That's a bit awkward, since $G$ will generally not be irreducible here; for example, the terminal letters are terminal letters because they can never lead to any others.
What's going to happen is that $\lambda(G)$ will correspond to an eigenvector that's positive on some strongly connected component: whichever strongly connected component we can get the most paths in by looping around inside it. In the example in the question, the letters $\{S, A, R, T\}$ form a strongly connected component, and the initial and terminal letters are all components of their own. So we'll get growth rate proportional to $|\lambda(G)|^k$ from words that wander between the letters S, A, R, T a lot. This is pretty much the best case, but we should worry about the following:

Irrelevant components of the graph that cannot be reached from any initial letter. Obviously these should be discarded before analyzing the graph.
If the strongly connected component with the largest eigenvalue can only be reached from some initial letters, or can only lead to some terminal letters, things will still be fine, but we'll be able to say that the majority of valid words for large $k$ will have the initial and terminal letters that can be involved with this component.
If multiple strongly connected components have the same (or equally large) largest eigenvalues, then we'll get multiplicity, and then we might see a polynomial factor on top of the exponential growth.
The matrix $G$ will be nilpotent, with largest eigenvalue $0$, if the graph has no cycles. In this case, for sufficiently large $k$, there will be no valid words.
In almost all cases, $|\lambda(G)|>1$. The exception is if all the strongly connected components are just cycles, with no internal branching. In this case, we'll have $|\lambda(G)|=1$ and we'll see polynomial growth in the number of valid words, depending on how many such components there are and how they're connected; the analysis here is a bit more complicated.


What would be a good reference text for this? I poked around in my library at the combinatorics and graph theory books, but being a statistician, my combinatorics is not as advanced as this.

I found a similar question here but I think it's about counting walks in undirected graphs. (In directed graphs, the story is a bit more complicated, because $G$ is not necessarily diagonalizable.) Still, that question points to Richard Stanley's Algebraic Combinatorics, which I think might be a good source to consult.
